# Актуальный способ использовать шрифт из ресурсов в WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, шрифты

Перечитал кучу зарубежных и не очень форумов, но никак не могу найти актуальную информацию о добавлении шрифта в ресурсы, и его использовании. Пожалуйста, сделайте подробный гайд по этому вопросу. Вариант хранения шрифта в папке с проектом не подходит.

Шрифт нужен для использования в лейблах и текстбоксах.

Comment: @defaultlocale исправил вопрос.

Comment: Можете посмотреть здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556147/how-to-quickly-and-easily-embed-fonts-in-winforms-app-in-c-sharp

Comment: @defaultlocale оформите пожалуйста как ответ. Если поможет, я вас плюсану и отмечу как правильный)

Comment: Решения по ссылке похожи на правду, но сам я их не использовал и сейчас не имею возможности протестировать, поэтому не стал писать ответ. Попробуйте, если получится, то сами сможете дать подробный ответ на свой вопрос.

Comment: @defaultlocale не работает. Есть еще способы?